# start an application which closes another application what is already running

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, process

I want a python script that terminate an aplications when I RUN another program.
Example: if I run vlc media player that will close kodi.exe
Or any other options to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you have to do is enumerate processes by name, determine which to kill, and then kill it (the last part may be cumbersome a bit).

Did you have a chance to look at the following questions and their answers (they illustrate how to handle all of the steps above)?

1. [Determining running programs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429250/determining-running-programs-in-python)
2. [List running processes on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632234/list-running-processes-on-64-bit-windows)
3. [Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

Comment: thank you ! I've used taskkill command and the subprocess.Popen command to open program it did work though but did try another program to taskkill but it doesn't kill the program..

Comment: Good to know it worked for you. Could you please indicate this marking the reply? Thank you.