# Check if there is an active window in Python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I want to know whether or not there *is* an active window on a windows 10 machine. I've tried out other methods on stack overflow, but they all get confused between windows with no title and no active window. I would really appreciate a fool-proof way to detect this.

Is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining running programs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429250/determining-running-programs-in-python)

Comment: No, @RahulARanger. Thanks for trying, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: is that related to Tkinter window

Comment: Yes, @RahulARanger. I'm trying to build an application which stays on by desktop like those windows 7 desktop widgets, or like Rainmeter widgets. I'm finding it really hard to do.

Comment: @Akhliesh try PySimpleGUI

Comment: Yes, @RahulARanger, I looked at some projects that used it. Thanks for the idea! However, it would be nice to do this with only Tkinter.